# Iterating through 2D array in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, matrix, kotlin

I'm having some trouble iterating my array of booleans. The problem is that I have four positions that should activate my if condition but it only detects one. I think it's because I'm iterating through in a bad way. There is my code so you can understand my problem:

Declaration of arrays:

```
  var columns = BooleanArray(Constants.WIDTH){ false }
    var lines = BooleanArray(Constants.HEIGHT){false}
```

Here I'm only checking on which positions shall I enable the true state and as you can see, I'm iterating in deep into the matrix:

```
fun addNewIPiece(positionX:Int,positionY:Int){
        val matrixPositionX = positionX/Constants.WIDTH_BLOCK
        val matrixPositionY = positionY/Constants.HEIGHT_BLOCK
        columns[matrixPositionX] = true
        for(i in 0..4){
            lines[matrixPositionY+i] = true
        }    
    }
```

Here I'm iterating through both columns and lines and drawing some blocks but somewhat, I'm only getting one coincidence(check below the code):

```
fun drawMap(monoBlock: MonoBlock,canvas: Canvas){
        for(columnsList in columns ){
            for (linesList in lines){
                if (columnsList and linesList)  {
               Log.d("CoincidenceX",columns.indexOf(columnsList).toString())
                Log.d("CoincidenceY",lines.indexOf(linesList).toString())                        monoBlock.draw(canvas,columns.indexOf(columnsList),lines.indexOf(linesList))
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the debug:

```
D/CoincidenceY: 87
D/CoincidenceX: 20
D/CoincidenceY: 87
D/CoincidenceX: 20
D/CoincidenceY: 87 ...........
```

So anyone can figure out where my mistake come from? I think its in the way that I iterate but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance, ask if you have any question.

Comment: please edit your code with the code that you declaring the variables columnsList and linesList

Comment: Done, sorry for the incomplete code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type of the variables `columnsList` and `linesList` (totally inappropriate names) is `Boolean` which is a [primitive](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/primitive-data-types-and-their-limitations.html) data type and they have values `true` or `false`.
 So when you use `indexOf()` it returns the index of the first item that matches the value of `columnsList` or `linesList` and not the index of the item you are currently iterating.
Since you are interested in the indexes, use an indexed loop :

```
for (i in columns.indices) {
    for (j in lines.indices) {
        if (columns[i] && lines[j]) {
            Log.d("CoincidenceX", i.toString())
            Log.d("CoincidenceY", j.toString())
        }
    }
}
```